# How to evaluate my MLPClassifier model? Is ROC curve needed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification, mlp

How to evaluate my MLPClassifier model? Is confusion matrix, accuracy, classification report enough? Do i need ROC for evaluating my MLPClassifier result? And aside from that how can i plot loss for test and training set, i used loss_curve function but it only show the loss plot for training set.

Ps. I'm dealing with multi-class classification problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very open question and with no code, so I will answer you with what I think is best. Usually for multi-label classification problem it is standard to use `accuracy` as a measure to track training. Another good measure is called `f1-score`. Sklearn's [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) is a very good method to track training.

**Confusion matrices** come **after** you train the model. They are used to check where the model is failing by evaluating which classes are harder to predict.

ROC curves are, usually, for **binary classification** problems. They can be adapted to multi-class by doing a one class vs the rest approach.

For the losses, it seems to me you might be confusing things. **Training** takes place over `epochs`, testing does not. If you train over 100 epochs, then you have 100 values for the loss to plot. **Testing does not use epochs**, at most it uses batches, therefore plotting the loss does not make sense. If instead you are talking about **validation** data, then yes you can plot the loss just like with the training data.

Comment: I have also one question, is loss necessary to determine if classification model is fitted?

Comment: Absolutely, so loss tells you how well your model is learning the data. If your model makes predictions that are far off from reality then the loss values will be quite high, so during training when you see your loss values decreasing form epoch to epoch that is a good indication that the model is learning. Also it can give you indications of overfitting in some cases. All in all loss plots for training and validation are very good to assess the quality of training and to inspect for possible issues.